# Apple Push Notifications - When Registering for Notifications no Callbacks are received at all

Tags: iphone, installation, push

I've gone through all the steps as specified, am using a dev certificate with APN enabled and am calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: with the right flags in my app delegate.

Still, neither application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: nor application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: are being called. It looks like the registration request just gets stuck in transit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see the code? It sounds like you're doing it right.

Comment: Also, it would be worth running through the steps again to make sure your provisioning profile is set up correctly. http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW2

Comment: Alex: Copied and pasted from the OpenFeint developer's site. Also tested to make sure that registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is being called, and tested just calling it directly in my app delegate.

When I test it with a bad profile application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError does get called with the appropriate error description, so I know that it's going out. It's just that the success delegate never gets called.

Comment: Well, for the record this example doesn't work with my profile either:

http://github.com/gevermann/gmail-iphone-push/

So something must be wrong with the profile.

Comment: Ok, tried with another profile and it is at least prompting me to enable push at startup, however when I enable it an alert pops up asking me to connect to iTunes to use Push.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds silly, but it's bit me in the past: double-check your capitalization and parameter types. If a delegate method declaration isn't spot on your method won't get called, and you won't get any kind of warning.

Your best bet is to copy and paste the prototype from Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try your App on another device. If it works there...

I have the same Problem with one iPhone 3G (no jailbreak, no unlock). It somply dos not work with that phone. I tried updating to a newer iPhone OS. I tried a factory reset. It does show the confirmationscreen and it records the answer in the Settings. But neither application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError nor application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken are ever called.

The same App works on all other tested devices (ipods, iphones). This iPhone 3G does also not receive PNs for other apps.

PNs also did not work for one Jailbroken Classic iPhone.

It might be that your device is simply not behaving correctly. Try a different device.

Comment: Is the Jailbroken phone carrier activated or hacktivated?

If it isn't carrier activated then push does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and it was because of bad certificates, app id, provision profile...

Make sure that:
1, Correct certificates are installed on client AND server
2, Make sure that you have selected correct provision profile in your project settings. REMEMBER  App ID in your provision profile has to be specific(not ending with *) and last part of this App ID has to match name of your application exactly and it is case sensitive. so iv your app is called myApp then your app id has to be  SOMENUMBERScom.yourcompany.myApp

Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by disconnecting from the cellular network. Seems to be some problem when both wireless and 3G are on concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that PUSH notifications require port 5223 open in your network (if you are using WIFI), or otherwise, a cellular data connection.

I encountered the same problem in my home network, and had to open the port manually in the wireless router.